# Adding dynamic data to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table

I've the following table in my application. I've a ajax request which will fetch the results to be shown in the table. How add these results to the table without overriding the header every time?

```
<table id="itemList">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Total</td>
</table>
```

Then the ajax data is as shown below

```
var items = [
    { Name: "Apple", Price: "80", Quantity : "3", Total : "240" },
    { Name: "Orance", Price: "50", Quantity : "4", Total : "200" },
    { Name: "Banana", Price: "20", Quantity : "8", Total : "160" },
    { Name: "Cherry", Price: "250", Quantity : "10", Total : "2500" }
];
```

Now I'm trying something like this but it is not working

```
var rows = "";
$.each(items, function(){
    rows += "<tr><td>" + this.Name + "</td><td>" + this.Price + "</td><td>" + this.Quantity + "</td><td>" + this.Total + "</td></tr>";
});

$( "#itemList" ).text('<tr><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Quantity-</td><td>Total</td></tr>' + rows  );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this by making two changes.

You can modify you html as

```
<table id="itemList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And Script as

```
var rows = "";
$.each(items, function(){
    rows += "<tr><td>" + this.Name + "</td><td>" + this.Price + "</td><td>" + this.Quantity + "</td><td>" + this.Total + "</td></tr>";
});

$( rows ).appendTo( "#itemList tbody" );
```

You can find a working solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2j9qG/).

But a jquery plugin called [templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) is built for this purpose.

Using jquery templates it can be solved as given below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            <tr>
                <td>${Name}</td>
                <td>${Price}</td>
                <td>${Quantity}</td>
                <td>${Total}</td>
            </tr>
        </script>

        <table id="itemList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var items = [
                    { Name: "Apple", Price: "80", Quantity : "3", Total : "240" },
                    { Name: "Orance", Price: "50", Quantity : "4", Total : "200" },
                    { Name: "Banana", Price: "20", Quantity : "8", Total : "160" },
                    { Name: "Cherry", Price: "250", Quantity : "10", Total : "2500" }
                ];

                $( "#itemTemplate" ).tmpl( items ).appendTo( "#itemList tbody" );
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But if you are further interested you go deep into some other plugins like [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) or [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) which are quite good grid data frameworks using jQuery.

Comment: + 1Probably good to use `th` rather than `td` elements in the `thead` as well. Also, when building up markup for display, it's faster on every implementation I've run across to build an array of string snippets and then use `.join('')` to join them into one string at the end, rather than constantly doing string concatenation.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using some form of templating solution.  Building tables by hand like this by mixing HTML into your JavaScript is just going to cause headaches later on, and it will probably be the poor chap who comes along after you're long gone and has to maintain your code who will ultimately suffer :)

Comment: @Crowder yes you are right, It is copy paste mistake. Better to use `th` under `thead`. Thanks regarding the performance gains in using array `join()` instead of using string concatenation all the time. I'll keep it in my mind for future development. Can you tell me any specific reasons for that change in performance>

Comment: @jmort Yes you are absolutely correct. I'd go for either the template base solution or use jqgrid. (Note: the microsoft/jquery template is still in beta so I don't think it will be good idea to use it in production environment)

Comment: Actually, I think that's all the more reason to use it.  Something that's in beta now probably won't be in beta once your product is on the market.  Something that is in production now might be obsolete by the time you produce a final product.  Don't doom yourself to outdated obscurity before you even ship your first release :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with JQuery, check out the [JQuery Temaplate](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/).  Might look like little convoluted but it would be a better approach, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to 2011!  Happy New Year!  We live in a wonderful and exciting time!  No more does a web developer ever have to worry about the details of manually building a table again... ever.

http://datatables.net/ will solve just about any problem you could possibly conceive.  The developers of this plug-in have thought of it all.  They've solved this problem so that you don't have to, which allows you to focus on your business goals.

I can't emphasize enough how powerful this JQuery plug-in is.  Please take a look at all of the numerous examples on their site.  They even have an example of how to dynamically add a row: http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html.

Disclaimer:  I had nothing to do with the development of DataTables.  I'm just really excited about it because it's made my life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The Table structure was wrong, need to use `<tbody>` and `<thead>`, [here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSKVR/F53BN/2/).

```
<table id="itemList">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to stand alone. By all means provide a link to a live example, but include all relevant markup and code in the answer itself (along with an explanation of what you did). External links can move, get deleted, etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I started on this example when there was 0 answers. I *am* presently elaborating, but am a little late ... considering Arun beat me to the punch. Best Practice: Delete or Finish?